# Thread Safety with Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0

If I have a

```
Dictionary<int, StreamReader> myDic = new Dictionary<int, StreamReader>
//Populate dictionary
```

One thread does

```
myDic[0] = new StreamReader(path);
```

Another thread does

```
myDic[1] = new StreamReader(otherpath)
```

Is this thread safe because the actual item in the dictionary getting modified is different to the one on the other thread or will I get a `InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You will only get `InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified` if you **enumerate** the dictionary while modifying.

However, that is not thread-safe.
If one of those operations causes the dictionary to resize, the other one may get lost.
Instead, use `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Comment: , What if I have cuncorrentDictionary and I need to check containsKey and then do something if true : then still I'd have to lock it  : ` lock (locker)
            {
                if (MyConDic.ContainsKey(toUserName))
                {...}}`....no?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: That defeats the whole purpose of `ConcurrentDictionary`.  Use its APIs

Comment: But who gurantees that in line 96 there wont be another thread which will add the entery ?http://i.stack.imgur.com/MwDuU.jpg ? please elaborate

Comment: Yes; don't do that.  Instead, use atomic APIs like `GetOrAdd()`.  See the docs.

Comment: I have never had an issue using the assignment operator in parallel (as, indeed, this is just what `.ToDictionary()` might do. I have asked a clarification question based on your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28749065/assigning-to-a-dictionary-in-parallel

Comment: @SLaks This answer from Jon Skeet seems to indicate that it can used with parallel assignments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612253/parallel-linq-use-more-threads-than-processors-for-non-cpu-bound-tasks

Comment: @Matthew: No; that's exactly the opposite of what he's saying.

Answer (score 5):

[System.Collections.Generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0sbxh9x2.aspx) collections are only thread safe if you are reading from multiple threads.

Quoting from MSDN

**System.Collections.Generic collection classes do not provide any thread synchronization; user code must provide all synchronization when items are added or removed on multiple threads concurrently**

If you want want thread safety for both read and write operations consider using [System.Collections.Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx)

**When you write new code, use the concurrent collection classes whenever the collection will be writing to multiple threads concurrently. **

Answer (score 1):

To improve your code, you might want to look up the `ConcurrentDictionary` class. It will solve some problems with multi-threading.