# Can I assign to a dictionary in parallel when that dictionary might resize?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, parallel-processing

Based on another answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8182978/369775

This claims that I cannot assign to a dictionary in parallel. I have never encountered an issue with assigning to a collection and worrying about its expanding its own size.

If I extend from that answer I think it says that I cannot do this contrived example:

```
Dictionary<int,int> foo = GetFoo();
var bar = new Dictionary<int,int>();

Parallel.ForEach(foo, bat=>
    {
        bar[bat.Key] = bat.Value
    }
```

This makes assignments to the dictionary in parallel the underlying collection `bar` might be resizing itself as needed.

It is very similar to what would be happening in this parallel assignment discussion from Jon skeet:
 [Parallel Linq - Use more threads than processors (for non-CPU bound tasks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612253/parallel-linq-use-more-threads-than-processors-for-non-cpu-bound-tasks)

I seems to me that I should not need to use a `ConcurrentDictionary` in the situation above but the answer I linked (from a notable user I respect) indicates otherwise.

Is it safe to use the `Dictionary` collection in the manner I described or will it fail?

Can somebody provide an code example where this sort of assigning will fail? I am trying to recognize the answers from SLaks and Jon Skeet with both explore assigning to a `Dictionary` in parallel.

**EDIT** Can the downvoter explain how I can improve my question? If what I'm asking is unlcear please explain how I can clarify. Thanks.

Comment: Yes; you cannot do that.   Why do you want to do that in the first place?

Comment: Even if it was perfectly pre-sized, it's not safe to write to a dictionary from multiple threads. Try writing down the pseudo-code for a hashmap insert and you'll see why (there's more than one step involved, and each step depends on shared data from the previous step not having changed).

Comment: @SLaks This is a very contrived example, but it's completely reasonable that assignments to a dictionary might be called by various threads just due to DI.

Comment: You can however perform any logic you need to on the key/value pairs you're creating beforehand and simply `lock` the dictionary the moment you're ready to add the pair. Limiting the lock to the simple act of assigning the key/value pair. I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: "I seems to me that I should not need to use a ConcurrentDictionary..." why? You just read that you do.

Comment: @itsme86 because I am looking for an example demonstrating why it would be needed.

Comment: Because one of the threads could be interrupted at any point in the middle of this mess of code (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,fd1acf96113fbda9).

Comment: @Matthew The thread safety of a class is not proven by the absence of a code example. If no code examples are posted here, you will still not have an answer to your real question.

Comment: @itsme86 if adding content breaks that model then Dictionaries (or any non-Concurrent collections) cannot be used in singletons even with locks.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis that's a fair criticism. I am trying to reconcile the discussions from SLaks and Jon Skeet in different, but related, answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign to a dictionary in parallel because the writes of the Dictionary class say it isn't thread safe. The details as to why aren't terribly important to the discussion.

If you are reading from a static dictionary you can do that from multiple threads as none of the reading options modify the underlying dictionary, but no updates are safe from multiple threads.

Feel free to walk through the [logic](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,fd1acf96113fbda9) and see why concurrent updates could fail if you want to know exactly why, but typically it is best to take the algorithm implementors word, as it is safer to assume someone else's logic was written with concurrent writing in mind it does not support it.

The simplest example of multiple writes failing is lines 352/353 which are (not so obviously) in the hot path for this method and involve copying a value followed by incrementing it.